# Better way to store json data in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql

I have json documents, like this https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7643#section-8.2, as you can see the document has several complex, multivalued attributes as well. Here each document is a separate identity.

In Postgres, I plan to store each key in separate column, for example "emails" attribute will be in different row and "name" will be in different row.

Does this make any sense, or should i just dump whole JSON as a single document as it is.

Comment: Maybe this: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-json/ and this: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html will help you took a decision.

Comment: Dealing with an EAV model is much harder then with a single JSON value, so if you want to go down the road of de-normalization, store it in a single `jsonb` column. But why not create a properly normalized model with a table `users` and one-to-many relationships to the tables `address` and `email`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, i don't think  having separate table for each property works, because clients have the provision to extend schema and might have to keep track of too many tables. Comparing EAV and single JSON which do you think will be costly for reading/writing.

Comment: I am using postgres database

Comment: It depends on your load: how data are inserted and which queries will be executed. In general, storing in relations will allow to utilise PG features and optimisations better.

Comment: Some of your JSON attributes are key candidates (id, externalId, userName, nickName, profileUrl for example). Others are not. Put the key candidates in separate columns. Put everything else in a single JSON document. So you will have both good performance and the freedom of extending the schema.